# How to find buyers with minimum 3 orders after optin date for the following 15 day period

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I'm looking for a way to find all buyers who registered for the sales promotion in November 2022 only and also made at least 3 orders for the following 15 day period after the registration(OPTINDATE).

Here is my query that doesn't work:

```
SELECT ID, OPTINDATE,ORDERDATE, COUNT(ORDER)  
FROM BUYER  
INNER JOIN PURCHASE USING(ID)  
WHERE OPTINDATE between '2022-11-01' and '2022-11-30'  
AND ORDERDATE > OPTINDATE(day,15) 
GROUP BY ID  
HAVING COUNT(ORDER)>= 3;
```

I'Ve got syntax error.

Comment: *Ive got syntax error* is useless as a problem description. You need to post the **complete, exact error message**. It's on the screen right in front of you, so there is no excuse for you not to include it in your post. You're asking us to help you solve **your problem**, and you should make it as easy as possible for us to do so by giving us the details you already have.

Answer (score 0):

This part doesn't make sense:

```
OPTINDATE(day, 15)
```

Perhaps you wanted to use the
[ADDdate](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_adddate) function:

```
ADDDATE(OPTINDATE, 15)
```

Comment: I always get the ADDdate function doesn't exist error.

Comment: This answer should better be a comment